# How will Arqade handle the cutsom games available in the soon to be released Reborn client for DotA 2

Tags: discussion

Just like the old Warcraft 3 days, Valve is bringing with Reborn [the possibility for people to create and host custom-made games](http://www.dota2.com/reborn/part2). Those gamemodes will be playable within the DotA 2 Reborn client and accessible to everybody.

Some of those mods (e.g. *Overthrow*, *Dota 2 Horde Mode*, *Pudge Wars* etc.) already count hundreds of thousands of subscribers.

Will question about those mods be allowed and if yes how should they be tagged ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are any specific tags even needed?  We don't have any custom game tags for Starcraft 2, Warcraft 3, League of Legends, you name it.

Questions about the custom modes will be on-topic, no issues there.  But we don't need a specific tag denoting that fact.  Not unless we actually get hundreds of questions for those specific game modes.  If there are already hundreds of thousands of subscribers, and we still don't need a tag for custom games, I think it's safe to say we won't need one.

Comment: Minecraft would be a good example of how we have handled this in the past, with the hundreds of thousands of mods and modpacks out there. If a mod is popular enough, we have a tag for it. I agree we should wait and see how many questions we actually get though. :)

Comment: Seems reasonable, I didn't know SC2 had mods and W3 being old I wasn't surprise to not see many questions about it. The way Minecraft is handled on the other hand is great. So yeah Just wait and see.

Answer (score -3):

**Yes**, those question will be on topic on Arqade. I suggest the creation of a generic tag for custom games. Something along the line [dota-2-custom-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dota-2-custom-game)